# Why don't CSS media queries work in my Tailwind/Svelte project?

Tags: css, media-queries, tailwind-css, svelte

I have a Svelte project that uses Tailwind CSS for styling.
I added the below media query code in the Tailwind CSS file inside `@layer components { ... }`:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1100) {
  .toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  header nav {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

But it does not work when I change the width of the browser.

I even checked in inspect element, but it appears as if the media query doesn't even exist in the browser.

Why does the CSS media query not work and how can I fix it?

Comment: missing units in your max-width declaration it should be something like this `@media only screen and (max-width: 1100px)`

Comment: Why did you add media queries, instead of taking advantage of Tailwind's responsive selectors? Also, you're missing a measurement for your query; `1100` = `1100px`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want your current code to work you need to add "px" to your max-width in media query, like this:

```
media only screen and (max-width: 1100px)
```

However, you don't need to do that in tailwind, preferable way would be adding screens to your tailwind.config.js, like this:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: {
      'sm': '640px',
      // => @media (min-width: 640px) { ... }

      'md': '768px',
      // => @media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

      'lg': '1024px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1100px) { ... }

      'xl': '1280px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1280px) { ... }

      '2xl': '1536px',
      // => @media (min-width: 1536px) { ... }
    }
  }
}
```

In your code you need to do something like this:

```
className='md:block hidden'
```

Read this page for further info: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens

**update**

When working with media queries it is better go with mobile-first approach and use min-width, rather than max-width